# C++11 Date / Times with Fractional Seconds

Tags: c++, c++11, datetime

**Does anybody know of a fast, portable way for parsing date/time strings which contain fractional seconds?**

For example:

```
2017-10-23T07:23:08.78
```

Thus far I can parse everything else with:

```
std::tm tm = {};
std::stringstream datestr("2017-10-23T07:23:08.78");
datestr >> std::get_time(&tm, "%Y-%m-dT%H:%M:%S.??");
```

The above snippet was modified from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21021388/how-to-parse-a-date-string-into-a-c11-stdchrono-time-point-or-similar) post.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37856887/how-do-i-parse-a-date-time-string-that-includes-fractional-time) other post shows the clever trick of parsing the year twice.  Unfortunately, since the fractional second is the last field in my representation, it will overwrite whatever valid field I actually want to use.

The reference documentation ([here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/get_time)) does not list any conversion specifier for fractional seconds nor does it list any specifier which can be used to match and discard arbitrary digits (same as `%t` or `%n` for whitespace.

To be clear, I am perfectly OK with discarding this portion of the precision.  I would prefer not to manipulate it with raw string functions but that seems the only option I can find.

Finally, this string is coming from a remote server so the format is out of my control.  My environment is currently Posix though I would prefer as much portability as reasonably possible.

---

**Edit:**  This question has been flagged as a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33421450/c-c-time-zone-correct-time-conversion-to-seconds-since-epoch).  I do not believe this to be so as my question is specifically about parsing / discarding tokens which do not have a character specifier. This is unique from the other post which uses, for example, `%z` to parse timezone (of which I am also not interested in).  My question is specifically targeted at *parsing*, not interpretation of the resultant value.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C/C++ time zone correct time conversion (to seconds since epoch)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33421450/c-c-time-zone-correct-time-conversion-to-seconds-since-epoch)

Comment: Well, a `std::tm` doesn't have anywhere to put fractional seconds. So it's hard to imagine doing anything other than just getting the last value yourself after `get_time` advances the stream.

Comment: i use date.h from howardhinnant - totally works fine for me :D https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date/blob/master/include/date/date.h https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/date.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Building on the great comment from [inxoy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6267827/inxoy) above, here is how you could do it with [Howard Hinnant's, free, open-source, portable, datetime library](https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/date.html):

```
#include "date/date.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

int
main()
{
    std::stringstream datestr("2017-10-23T07:23:08.78");
    date::sys_time<std::chrono::milliseconds> tp;
    datestr >> date::parse("%FT%T", tp);
    if (datestr.fail())
        return 1;
    std::cout << date::format("%F %T\n", tp);
}
```

`date::sys_time<std::chrono::milliseconds>` is a type alias for a `std::chrono::system_clock::time_point`, except with `milliseconds` precision (you can use any precision you want).

`"%F"` is a short cut for `"%Y-%m-%d"`, you can use either interchangeably.

If you want it in a `std::tm`, the [wiki page shows how to do this](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date/wiki/Examples-and-Recipes#components_to_time_point), along with tons of other example code.

The program above portably outputs:

```
2017-10-23 07:23:08.780
```

I could have instead used:

```
std::chrono::system_clock::time_point tp;
```

and this would have changed my output to:

```
2017-10-23 07:23:08.780000
```

The `%T` formatter will output whatever precision your `time_point` has, and the `%T` parser will parse up to as many decimal digits as your `time_point` has.

`"date/date.h"` doesn't do time zones.  It is strictly UTC (technically [Unix Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time)).  If you need to work with time zones (or leap seconds), there is an additional [free, open-source IANA time zone library](https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/tz.html) available which builds on top of `"date/date.h"`.

Comment: What is the additional time (on average, as a rough percentag estimate) for using your library over basic STL time functions?  I ask as this is going into API response code so performance is a bit of a concern.  A 10% time increase will not break the bank but, say,  doubling parse time will be a problem.

Comment: If what you're comparing to is another solution parsing from `std::istringstream`, very competitive.  The main expense can be the actual use of C++ I/O itself.  `date/date.h` is a header-only library (with only one header), so it is very easy for you to download from GitHub and run a timing experiment.  Just point at the header and go.

Comment: Hmmm... and now that I think about it, use of `"%F"` over `"%Y-%m-%d"` is going to shave a few cycles off since the parser only has to parse one command instead of 3.